# How to Automatically turn ON GPS on Android?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova

how to turn on GPS automatically or Ask a Permission turn on GPS when the script run function for get latitude and longitude ?

i run in ripple

and its automatically turn on "GPS" on my chrome, but when i build and run in my Android Smartphone, the GPS wont show up.

i already add "GeoLocation" plugin in config, but still wont work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An app can't automatically turn on GPS on Android. The best it can do is detect if GPS is switched on/off and then open the Android Location Settings page if the latter.

You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to do this, for example:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
    if(!enabled){
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
    }
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Note that if GPS is switched off on Android, the Geolocation API will return timeout error rather than permission denied. If a position watch was added using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` while GPS was switched off, once GPS is switched on, you'll need to clear the watcher and add it again before the watcher will call the success function.

**UPDATE**

You can use [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to request high accuracy location mode (i.e. GPS) directly from within the app. This will show a native confirm dialog and if user agrees, GPS will be enabled automatically with requiring user to manually change settings:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success){
    console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);
}

function onRequestFailure(error){
    console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
    if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
        if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        }
    }
}

cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```